# how to display mysql data using drop down?

Tags: php, mysql

here is what i came up,
i could insert a data into my "gender" field, but when I'm in edit/update page, i want the "gender" field only displays "Select One" value, not "male/Female"

thanks in advance

```
<form action='#' method='post' border='0'>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <select name="gender" id="gender">
   <option>Select One</option>
   <option>Male</option>
   <option>Female</option>
   </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <td>
  <input type='hidden' name='id_number' value='<? php echo $id_number ?>' />
  <input type='hidden' name='action' value='edit' />
  <input type='submit' value='Edit' />
 </td>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: You display MySQL data by connecting to the database, submitting a query, and displaying the result set.

Comment: I think you need to specify your question a little bit more. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: the display page has no problem, it displays Male/Female, but when I click edit and go to edit/update page, the drop down menu value is still in "Select One" not the previously selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an attribute named `selected="selected"` to the `<option>` tag that you want selected by default.

Comment: sorry for the innocence, but where and how should I add that?

Comment: add something like `<? if ($gender = 'male') { echo "selected='selected'" } ?>` *inside* of the Male `<option>` tag, and so something similar for Female.

Comment: like this?

<option><? if ($gender = 'Male') { echo "selected='selected'" } ?> Male</option>
<option><? if ($gender = 'Female') { echo "selected='selected'" } ?>Female</option>

did not work

but this one:

<option selected="selected">Male</option>
<option selected="selected">Female</option>

works but "Female" becomes the default value, not "Select One"

Comment: got the problem this way

    <option value="Male" <?php if ($gender == "Male") echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>Male</option>
    <option value="Female" <?php if ($gender == "Female") echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>Female</option>

thanks for all the Ideas

Answer (score 0):

Simply import the $gender value from the db into the edit page and then add this :

```
<select name="gender" id="gender">
    <option>Select One</option>
    <option <?if $gender=="Male" echo 'selected="selected"'?>>Male</option>
    <option <?if $gender=="Female" echo 'selected="selected"'?>>Female</option>
</select>
```

Thats it friend.I hope it will useful for you much